# iframe in salesforce modal pop up, entire page greys out

Tags: popup, modal-dialog, salesforce

[CSS Modal window and iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757961/css-modal-window-and-iframe)

I am using the code in the above link to show modal pop up in salesforce. When i put Iframe in the modal pop-up the entire page greys out. Any idea what needs to be corrected?

Comment: can you be more specific please

Comment: The code works fine if i put normal apex tags in the modal pop-up. But when i put a iframe entire page grey's out on click of button. code used is in the below link http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace

```
<apex:page controller="tstpopup">
```

with

```
<apex:page controller="tstpopup" showHeader="false">
```

This should help when rendering in an iFrame.

I hope this helps. Cheers.